# Error 'Type Aspose.Words.Document' is not defined.' when trying to compile

Tags: .net, visual-studio, assemblies, reference, aspose

In visual studio, I create a reference to the Aspose assembly and use the Document class in my code. It looks fine at design-time, but when I go to compile I get the error 'Type Aspose.Words.Document' is not defined.' If I do anything that changes the project file, like add or drop a reference or add a new file, the errors go away... until I try to compile again.

Has anyone else seen this weird behavior and know how to fix it? Here's my code if it matters, but it doesn't get much simpler:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim license As New Aspose.Words.License()
        license.SetLicense("Aspose.Words.lic")

        Dim files = My.Resources.files.Split()

        For Each file In files
            If file <> "" Then
                Dim changed As Boolean = False
                Console.Write("Processing " & file & "...")

                Dim doc = New Aspose.Words.Document(file)

                If doc.Range.FormFields("CurrDate") IsNot Nothing Then
                    doc.Range.FormFields("CurrDate").TextInputType = Aspose.Words.Fields.TextFormFieldType.RegularText
                    doc.Range.FormFields("CurrDate").TextInputFormat = ""
                    doc.Save(file)
                    Console.WriteLine("done.")
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("not applicable.")
                End If

            End If

        Next
        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it must be because the dll is targeting a different framework than what was specified in the project. I created a new console app that targeted 3.5 instead of 4.0 and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Are there multiple libraries to reference? Also, where is your imports statement?

Comment: Only one library and I don't need an import statement because they're fully qualified, right?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're referencing the correct Aspose dll (the one containing the Document class). Verify the Document class is under the Aspose.Words namespace.

Crack open the dll inside [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to verify this stuff.

Comment: I'm using the correct dll. The document class shows in intellisense when I first add the dll. After I try to compile, it's like the reference was removed. Not even the "Aspose" namespace appears in intellisense anymore. If I drop the reference and add it back the errors go away and intellisense sees it again - until I try to compile again.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your environment. Does this happen with other dlls?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `Copy Local` on the assembly set to true and `Embed Intrerop` is set to false.

Comment: @adam0101 In solution explorer right click on an assembly under references, go to properties and you should see those listed there.